# Grouping rows of a table with brackets (to shrink table size)

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have a table using rules from `booktabs`. However, I have vertical space constraints and don't want to use `subcaption` with their `subtable`. I also have horizontal space constraints, so the column for the group should be minimal.

As a first approach, I do use `bigdelim` and brackets for grouping.

## MWE

A possible MWE looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, bigdelim, rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
\toprule
& header1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
\ldelim\{{4}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group1}}] & 1 & a & g \\
& 2 & b & h \\
& 3 & c & i \\
& 3 & c & i \\
\ldelim\{{6}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group2}}] & 4 & d & j \\
& 5 & e & k \\
& 6 & f & l \\
& 7 & g & m \\
& 8 & h & n \\
& 9 & i & o \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: grouping rows of a table]

However, I don't want to have the "group" column being captured by the horizontal lines, I don't think that is aesthetic. I used the `cmidrule` command from `booktabs` to reduce their length already. However, there is (understandably) no such thing for `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`

## Question

1. Is their a solution to have a `booktabs` without having the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` showing on the "group" column? *(I can only think of writing my own command for, e.g. `\ctoprule`, which is using `\cmidrule` but all rules from `\toprule` for, e.g., thickness and spaces, apply.)*
2. Is there a better solution to achieve that grouping with sticking to the `booktabs` package?

Comment: Why not use a horizontal line to separate the groups and remove the brackets?

Comment: That is an option @leandriis (also in addition to what I have so far). The groupX entries however will then look funny when rotated (but I need them rotated because of space constraints). Maybe I don't fully comprehend your suggestion though.

Comment: The following came to my mind: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eh18.png

Comment: Thank you! It for some reason doesn't appeal to me though, as the rotated text feels out of context and without a header for the column, it feels "untidy". I will give it a day and have a look again :)

Comment: According to section 5 in the [booktabs-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), trimming of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` is implemented for `longtable`. That package may be uses for all tabular, unless you need floating. Maybe you can build the table as a `longtable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a thicker `cmidrule`? As far as I can see, the spacing are approximately the same, and it can be adjusted. I also suggest to remove rightmost side bearing, and trim the left side of the `cmidrule`s. You may also consider to ad a small space between the groups, `0.75ex` was enough.

However, according to the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual section 5, [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) together with [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) implements trimming of all type of rules. The maintainer suggest to use [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) for tabulars if you need trimmable `toprule` and `bottomrule`. I have implemented this in the examples below. The trimming factor is little bit of guesswork, unless you set a fixed width of the first column, or has the skill to implement code to read the .aux-file or measure the first column. In the last version, [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) got new `W`- and `w`-columns, where you can specify alignment and width. I have used a 4mm `w`-column. The trimming factor should then be `4mm+2\tabcolseps+0.75ex` (standard trimming factor see manual p. 4):

### longtable

I have improve the code since yesterday:

1. I have changed the second parameter of `\ldelim` to `{*}` to get rid of two `Overfull hbox with 10.[...]pt` error message. It is still left an `Underfull vbox...` message, but I leave it for now.
2. I have changed the `\tabcolsep` to `0.5em` instead of a fixed number of point.
3. I increased the left column to `5 mm` and consequently the correction factor for the `toprule` and `bottomrule`. This gives a little more air in the tabular.
4. The correct trimming factor for `cmidrule` *etc*. should be `\tabcolsep`, not `0.75ex`. If you prefer, you may subtract 1pt so the line is not absolutely flush with the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, bigdelim, rotating, longtable, array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}   % As recommended by James Felici ‘The Complete Manual of Typography’
\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{longtable}[l]{w{l}{5mm}lcc@{}}
\toprule(l{\dimexpr(5mm+3\tabcolsep)})
& header1 & header 2 & header 3
\endfirsthead
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-4}
\ldelim\{{4}{*}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group1}}] & 1 & a & g \\
& 2 & b & h \\
& 3 & c & i \\
& 3 & c & i \\\addlinespace[0.75ex]
\ldelim\{{6}{*}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group2}}] & 4 & d & j \\
& 5 & e & k \\
& 6 & f & l \\
& 7 & g & m \\
& 8 & h & n \\
& 9 & i & o \\
\bottomrule(l{\dimexpr(5mm+3\tabcolsep)})
\end{longtable}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### tabular and modified cmidrule

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, bigdelim, rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{llcc@{}}
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){2-4}
& header1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
\ldelim\{{4}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group1}}] & 1 & a & g \\
& 2 & b & h \\
& 3 & c & i \\
& 3 & c & i \\\addlinespace[0.75ex]
\ldelim\{{6}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group2}}] & 4 & d & j \\
& 5 & e & k \\
& 6 & f & l \\
& 7 & g & m \\
& 8 & h & n \\
& 9 & i & o \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I assume your question was rhetorical, but yes, I thought about adapting `cmidrule` and make a custom command for `[top|buttom]rule` based on that (see question #1). However, I thought there might be more cleverness behind it then just the thickness.

Comment: @Marcus I wanted to give support to your principle to keep it simple.

Comment: thank you a lot for these two great solutions. I completely missed the part that `[top|bottom]rule` are trimmable when using longtable. Your both solutions look really nice and can be also processed with tools like, e.g., `csvsimple`. I personally prefer the `longtable` version as it seems to be the solution closest to the booktabs package.
Your suggested spacing between the groups makes it indeed more readable. Also, as you hinted in `longtable#4`, I ending up using `\cmidrule(l{\dimexpr(\tabcolsep-1pt)}){2-4}` so the rules don't perfectly align with the text of the first column.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @Marcus, it is important and motivating.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions: one based on custmised `\cmidrule`s that mimick `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, and another based on `blkarray`, with a simpler sy,tax, and only 3 columns. Unfortunately, the latter package is not compatible with `booktabs`, so I had to play with `\BAhhline` to obtain thicker rules and the correct spacing at top and bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, bigdelim, rotating}%{
\newcommand{\mytoprule}{\noalign{\vskip -\aboverulesep}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}}
\newcommand{\mybottomrule}{\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}\noalign{\vskip -\belowrulesep}}
\usepackage{blkarray, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
\mytoprule
& header1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
\ldelim\{{4}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group1}}] & 1 & a & g \\
& 2 & b & h \\
& 3 & c & i \\
& 3 & c & i \\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\ldelim\{{6}{4mm}[\parbox{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group2}}] & 4 & d & j \\
& 5 & e & k \\
& 6 & f & l \\
& 7 & g & m \\
& 8 & h & n \\
& 9 & i & o \\
\mybottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\doublerulesep =0.05pt
\begin{blockarray}{lcc}
\hhline{===}
\BAnoalign{\vskip -5.3ex}
 header1 & header 2 & header 3 \\
 \BAhline
\begin{block}{\Left{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group1}\,}{\{\,}lcc}
 1 & a & g \\
 2 & b & h \\
 3 & c & i \\
 3 & c & i \\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{\Left{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{group2}\,}{\{\,}lcc}%
 4 & d & j \\
 5 & e & k \\
 6 & f & l \\
 7 & g & m \\
 8 & h & n \\
 9 & i & o \\%\
\end{block}
\BAnoalign{\vskip -5.3ex}
\hhline{===}
\end{blockarray}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! I didn't do the custom commands myself but I was afraid that might be the best solution (see my question #1 comment). They look cool, thank you.

Comment: it is probably nice to use an argument for, e.g., `mytoprule`: `\newcommand{\mytoprule}[1]{\noalign{\vskip -\aboverulesep}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#1}}`. This allows for calling it similar to `\cmidrule` like `\mytoprule{2-4}`.

Comment: I guess you're right. I just wanted to save the user the hassle to have to type the range of columns each time, but  upon reflection there's little chance all tables will have the same number of columns.

Comment: @Bernard In addition option for spanning, an option for `left,`right` - trimming is necessary. Preferably with the same syntax with parentheses. Maybe it is possible to ask the maintainer to implement the syntax for `toprule` and `\bottomrule`.